# Angular.js - Filtering object by nested properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm looking for advice. My following code doesn't work, most likely because of the directive or the filter that don't get updated when the `$scope.clients` object changes:

```
$scope.clients = {
    "IDa": {"position": {index: 1}, "name": "a"},
    "IDb": {"position": {index: 2}, "name": "b"},
    "IDc": {"position": {index: 3}, "name": 'c'},
    "IDd": {"position": {index: 4}, "name": "d"},
    "IDe": {"position": {index: 5}, "name": "e"},
    "IDf": {"position": {index: 6}, "name": "f"},
    "IDg": {"position": {index: 7}, "name": "g"},
    "IDh": {"position": {index: 8}, "name": "h"},
    "IDi": {"position": {index: 9}, "name": "i"}
};
```

I need to display 7 items (divs) based on the position property. The tricky thing is that if there are less than 7 items in the object, the view must still have 7 items just instead of the name property it'll say 'Waiting for client'. The view must display those 7 items in the order of the position 1..7.

The HTML:

```
<div class="streams__unit" stream client="clients | position:1">
       {{ client.name || 'Waiting for client' }}
</div>
<div class="streams__unit" stream client="clients | position:2">
       {{ client.name || 'Waiting for client' }}
</div>
<div class="streams__unit" stream client="clients | position:3">
       {{ client.name || 'Waiting for client' }}
</div>
<div class="streams__unit" stream client="clients | position:4">
       {{ client.name || 'Waiting for client' }}
</div>
<div class="streams__unit" stream client="clients | position:5">
       {{ client.name || 'Waiting for client' }}
</div>
<div class="streams__unit" stream client="clients | position:6">
       {{ client.name || 'Waiting for client' }}
</div>
<div class="streams__unit" stream client="clients | position:7">
       {{ client.name || 'Waiting for client' }}
</div>
```

Here's the position filter:

```
angular.module('app').filter('position', function () {
    return function (clients, index) {
        var client = {};

        for(var i in clients) {
            if(clients[i].position.index === index) {
                client = value;
                break;
            }
        };

        return client;
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work since the clients object is updated later than the filter fires (i think). Here's the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('stream', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('client', function(val) {
                console.log('watch worked', val);
            });
        },
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, fn) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.client, function(client) {
                scope.client = client;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what you are trying to achieve? maybe a working example? Also, could this be achieved with a ng-repeat and a limitTo filter and a orderBy filter?

Comment: I'm afraid ng-repeat wouldn't work since the view MUST have 7 items in place. And it's object may have 0 or less than 7 items.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is a 2 step approach:

1. preprocess the object into the desirable array.
2. use ng-repeat with 'orderBy' filter and 'limitTo' filters applied.

Here's a plunker example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AYEvW9DmxdZEF9lVSD20?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in clientsArr | orderBy: 'position.index' | limitTo: 7" class="streams__unit">
   {{ item.name || 'Waiting for client' }}
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.clients = {
  "IDa": {"position": {index: 1}, "name": "a"},
  "IDb": {"position": {index: 2}, "name": "b"},
  "IDc": {"position": {index: 3}, "name": 'c'},
  "IDd": {"position": {index: 4}, "name": "d"},
  "IDe": {"position": {index: 5}, "name": "e"}
};

$scope.clientsArr = [];
for(var i in $scope.clients) {
  $scope.clientsArr.push({
      id: i,
      position: $scope.clients[i].position,
      name: $scope.clients[i].name
    });
  }

  while($scope.clientsArr.length < 7) {
    $scope.clientsArr.push({});
  }
});
```

Comment: I also need to watch for changes on the clients object, because some items can switch places (position.index changes), dynamically appear, dissapear, change property values and so on.

Comment: Also lets say I have items with indexes 1,2,4. I still need to have an empty item in position 3. And this code won't work in that case because it doesn't put the element in the right position.